# Swift compiler error while conforming to protocol by providing property via getter function

Tags: swift

I have a class that is attempting to conform to the `NSFilePresenter` protocol. As best I can tell, there are only two requirements, and they're both properties:

```
var presentedItemURL: NSURL! { get }
var presentedItemOperationQueue: NSOperationQueue! { get }
```

Because I'm migrating my existing Objective-C project to Swift, I already have one of these maintained as an ivar that I'd like to maintain:

```
var _trackingURL: NSURL! = ...

var presentedItemURL: NSURL! {
    return _trackingURL
}

var presentedItemOperationQueue: NSOperationQueue! {
    return NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
}
```

However, this build fails due to a 'Swift Compiler Error' in Xcode, but does not specify what I'm doing wrong. I have a stack trace from the compiler, but I can't decipher what the root issue is:

```
0  swift                    0x000000010b10b608 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40
1  swift                    0x000000010b10baf4 SignalHandler(int) + 452
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff92578f1a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fd0c225e968 _sigtramp + 802052712
4  swift                    0x000000010a74797a (anonymous namespace)::ObjCPrinter::visitVarDecl(swift::VarDecl*) + 762
5  swift                    0x000000010a746f7d swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::ObjCPrinter, void, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Decl*) + 125
6  swift                    0x000000010a74abcb (anonymous namespace)::ObjCPrinter::printMembers(swift::IteratorRange<swift::DeclIterator>) + 251
7  swift                    0x000000010a747603 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::ObjCPrinter, void, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Decl*) + 1795
8  swift                    0x000000010a74638e swift::printAsObjC(llvm::raw_ostream&, swift::Module*) + 1934
9  swift                    0x000000010a4d0b6e printAsObjC(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, swift::Module*) + 286
10 swift                    0x000000010a4d0178 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 3592
11 swift                    0x000000010a4cf35d main + 1533
12 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff978e45c9 start + 1

...

<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: merge-module command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

While it would be nice if the compiler were able to survive whatever I've done to it, I'd rather just remedy the issue in my code, whatever it is.

Comment: And as a side-question: What are these 'getter functions' called when the return value for a `var` is computed? It seems less like a getter, and more like a 'dynamic property', but I can't find an example of the right terminology.

Comment: This is definitely a bug in the compiler. Report it.

Comment: Definitely reporting it - I just came here to figure out what *I'm* doing wrong in my code, if anything.

Comment: Reported, I'll post back. rdar://17186304

Comment: Are there any workarounds?

Comment: I think I was able to workaround it by wrapping the return value in a `get` block, indicating explicitly that I was defining the implementation of a getter.

Comment: What Swift version are you using? Asking as `NSURL` should've been imported as `URL` in Swift 3&4

Comment: @Cristik I can't remember - whatever version was available in June 2014?

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't realize this is an older question :p

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, when I write such a dynamic property in a class extension:

```
class MyClass {
  func test() {
    let myVar = myProperty
  }
}

extension MyClass {
  var myProperty: String { return "TEST" }
}

MyClass().test()
```

This crashes XCode when placed in a playground, and it causes the build to fail with the cryptic "Swift Compiler Error" when such code is included in a `.swift` file in my project.

Might be related, in any case I reported it (rdar://17527780 I suppose).

Comment: It actually only occurs if at some point you *access* the property. If you never access it, the build succeeds.

Comment: Does it work any better if you define the `return` value inside a getter block? (`get { ... }`)